# to identify these services after upg. to andr 10?

Tags: updates, security, permissions

To all,

please tell me if this is relevant to the forum.

#### the problem:

I want to identify these services that appear after the upgrade to Android 10, in `adjustments -> applications and notifications -> manager of permissions -> storage` and other permissions. Some data:

- model: Nokia 4,2
- this model has the Android One distribution.

I didn't find anything in web search for this one:

- QMMI

in the search there appear titles such as "hidden settings" or something related to Xiaomi. the others are, in total:

- com.android.carrierconfig
- com.qualcomm.qti.workloadclassifier
- face

#### more observations:

- the election to uninstall or disable are not available for any these.
- until now, only user style titles appeared in permissions, such as `Chrome` or `Foo Service`, never something in the style of a kernel module `foo.bar.baz`

#### questions / ideas:

- Is this how it should be in a valid update of Android from Google?
- how to uninstall / to investigate: maybe I can enter a linux terminal? is it possible to create a root user with password, but not to disqualify of Android updates? also, it would be from inside the device: I would not open a server for this purpose intentionally.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: To test if the device is in a genuine state you can use the [Google SafetyNet attestation result e.g. shown in one of this apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=safetynet&c=apps). In any way if you don't trust the manufacturer of a device don't buy a device from him or at least unlock it and install LineageOS on it.

Comment: @Robert thans I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

The following observation supports a conclusion that this no more than a quirk of the last system update:

According to [this link to an Android package QMMI](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/hmd-global/qmmi-5/qmmi-5-4-0-release/qmmi-4-0-2-android-apk-download/), it seems that this is created by HMD Global [the company that produces Nokia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMD_Global).